# mount those which have nofail set in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

I want a command to mount all devices with the nofail option set in my /etc/fstab.

I thought:

```
sudo mount -a -O nofail --verbose
```

With an fstab like:

```
UUID=7C86176286171C68 /media/yes ntfs defaults,nofail 0 2
UUID=cb88f1f7-f7d3-4e7e-a849-96f0d6fced15 /media/no ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Running the command I get:

```
/media/yes        : successfully mounted
/media/no          : successfully mounted
```

I'd expect:

```
/media/yes        : successfully mounted
/media/no          : ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

`no` prefix is used to negate the `-O` option result so by using `-O nofail` you are actually telling `mount` to mount all filesystems that don't have `fail` option. To disable the `no` effect you need to use plus sign, e.g. `-O +nofail`.

This works for me with `nofail` set only for `/dev/sdc1`

```
$ sudo mount -a -O +nofail
$ lsblk /dev/sdc
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdc      8:32   0    1G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0    8M  0 part /mnt/yes
└─sdc2   8:34   0 1014M  0 part
```

I'd actually expect to find this in the mount man page, but it's not there, I found the information about the `+` usage only in the [libmount API documentation](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub//linux/utils/util-linux/v2.32/libmount-docs/libmount-Options-string.html#mnt-match-options).